# Is it possible to turn upside down an MapElement3D?

Tags: c#, uwp, bing-maps, uwp-maps

I have an `MapElement3D` that changes heading, pitch and roll. Heading is 0-360º, but pitch and roll have the limit of -90º - 90º angle, so I can't turn upside down an `MapModel3D`.

Is there any other way to achieve this without the creation of an copy of the `MapModel3D` turned upside down?

Answer (score 0):

The docs are incorrect in this case - you can specify pitch from -180 to +180 to flip the model. I also think you could get the same effect by setting the scale value on two axes to -1.

Comment: Even if you can specify values from -180 to 180º, MapElement3D doesn't rotate more than +/-90º.

Comment: Specifying a pitch of 180 does appear to flip the model as expected in a quick test app. https://imgur.com/a/N5nFIwB. Are you seeing something different?

Comment: Yes. model doesn't pitch values greater than 90º or lesser than -90º. Same for roll. 
Here are the screenshots of the model:
https://imgur.com/a/uXsEThc
I'm currently developing for:
https://imgur.com/a/ConS9uQ